# Is there anyway to query mongodb in cypress test?

Tags: cypress

I am looking to interact with mongodb from cypress test.I couldn't find any useful documentation.Please help me how to acheive this?

Answer (score 2):

Look at their documentation about tasks :https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html#Command

I needed to do something with mongodb and i managed to connect doing something like this (inside "plugins" directory):

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    updateTask (id) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', (err, client) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(`MONGO CONNECTION ERROR: ${err}`)  
            throw err;
          } else {
            const db = client.db('myDB');
            db.collection('someCollection').count({}, function(error, numOfDocs){              
              resolve({success: numOfDocs})
              client.close();
             })
          }
        });
      }); // end of return Promise
    }
  }) // end of task
}
```

and you call it inside "spec" like this:

```js
cy.task('updateTask', someParam).then((textOrNull) => {   
  console.log(textOrNull) 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is now a mongodb plugin for cypress: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-mongodb

After you configure it, you'll be able to call `cy` commands to perform actions in your local or remote db:

```
cy.createCollection(...);
cy.dropCollection(...);
cy.insertMany(...);
cy.aggregate(...);
```

Comment: I'm getting a bunch of dependency problems when trying this option: bson-ext, snappy, snappy-android-arm64... I seem to be unable to install this plugin properly, can you ellaborate your answer?

Comment: Could you share some code example? At which step do you get these errors? Just tried the latest version, no problems found

Comment: I created a new question on SO -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72015449/problems-installing-npm-cypress-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Execute a shell command from your cypress test:

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/exec.html#Syntax

Example:
`cy.exec(mongo mydatabase --eval 'db.collection.find({})')`