# Problems installing npm cypress-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, npm, cypress, npm-install

I'm trying to set up the plugin `cypress-mongodb` to use on our cypress framework, but I'm hitting a bit too many problems:

I have installed and configured the plugin following the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-mongodb), but when I launch my cypress IDE, I get an indefinite amount of dependencies missing:

> Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module 'bson-ext'

After installing bson-ext, then I get:

> Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module 'snappy'

And then, after installing snappy:

> Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module 'snappy-android-arm64'

At which point I'm giving up as my project should not be dependant of anything android related...

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Any kind of example code would be good to help reproduce the issue, as it works for me. I expect (but let's just confirm it) that you don't get this error when not using the plugin?

Comment: Hey Zaista, I've followed the environment setup explained on npm page, and code is simply the example to delete an entry: `cy.deleteOne({name:"abc"}, "db", "col")})`
and the error shows when doing `npm run cypress` and selecting the feature containing the code

Comment: Which mongodb version are you running on your system?