# How to run script in mongoDb during the cypress test

Tags: mongodb, cypress

I'm trying to run script in mongodb at the beginning of cypress test. I've added method in plugins/index.js to connect to mongo but I'm not sure what to do next. I've try to add in taks db.command with script, but it doesn't work. Any ideas, how I can do this ?

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')

const uri = "someUri"
if (!uri) {
    throw new Error('Missing MONGO_URI')
}

const client = new MongoClient(uri)
async function connect() {
    await client.connect()
    return client.db()
}

module.exports = async (on, config) => {

    const db = await connect()

    on('task', {


};
```

Comment: There is a plugin for that `cypress-mongodb`, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70304684/1757737

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to this if anybody will have same problem.

```
    on('task', {

        async updateCarColor() {
            await db.collection('collectionName').updateOne({"Id": "45"},
                {
                    "$set": {"car.color": "red"}
                })
            return null
        },
    })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).